# Binding a property to a control using Windows Forms Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, designer

I want to bind a property to a control using Windows Forms Designer.

For example, I have this component:

```
class MyComponent:Component, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _strProperty;
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string StrProperty {
      get{
        return _strProperty;
      }
      set {
        if (_strProperty != value) {
          _strProperty = value;
          if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StrProperty"));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I drag this component from the toolbox and drop it on a form.  The component name is myComponent1.  On the same form I have a TextBox control named textBox1.
Now I want to bind *textBox1.Text* property to *myComponent1.StrProperty* property.
I know that I can write in code:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myComponent1, "StrProperty"));
```

but I want to achieve the same result using the designer. Is it possible?  Should I use a BindingSource?

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is 3 years old I'm not sure this applied to your version of Visual Studio at the time but for others interested now here's how you can do it:

- select **textBox1**
- expand **(DataBindings)** in the property grid
- in **Text**, enter **myComponent1 - StrProperty**
- press **enter**, done

Simple as that. If you check the generated designer code you'll see the new binding created as you would have done it by code.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only binding the property using code-behind in WinForm. However, you can binding data in WPF without C# code but using XAML.